# remove empty div and parent

Tags: html, django, collections, tags

Hello I have a HTML that shows all the artworks based on their collections as bellow:now, the collection "No_COLLECTION" is empty but it shows it's collection name and an empty space. I tried to remove it but i couldn't. Please help me to remove all the collections that doesn't have artworks in them.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div id="main" style='min-height:800px;'>
{% with 'No_COLLECTION woodtest Test-2 Culture KASHAN HUMAN mine' as list %}
{% for i in list.split %}
<script>
    var level = 0;
</script>
    <div class="row" style="position: relative;margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div>{{i}}</div>
        <div  class="workSeriesThumbnailStrip">
      {% for obj in object_list  %}
              {% if obj.collection == i %}
                  <script>
                      var level = level+1;
                  </script>
                  <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" 
style="float:left;width:67px;height:87px;margin:10px;" ></a>
              {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <script>
        document.write(level);
    </script>
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
  <script>
  if ($('.workSeriesThumbnailStrip').is(':empty')) { 
    $('.row').remove();
  } 
 </script>

 {% endwith %}
 </div>


 <div class="clear"></div>
 {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add if statement. If the list is not empty, put your div inside that if statement body. else just div an empty div.

Comment: but list is a title of a collection. please say me where exactly should I put the if